# How to save all the cells in a jsf dataTable from a button

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces datatables in a form. My requirement to enable some columns for editing at cell level and disable editing rest of the columns. I used "Cell Editing with Click and RightClick" from the Primefaces showcase as an example to build my datatables. Here is the url http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

My form has other fields and few datatables and each datatable has lot of cells. There are some checks that need to happen on server side before saving the 'editable' cells.  So, instead of row editing or individual cell editing, I want to save all the cells in the datatable on clicking a command button.

Here is a column from my datatable.

```
            <p:column>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{employes.name}" /></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="name" value="#{employes.name}" />
                    </f:facet>                        
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
```

I am losing the value of cell as soon as I modify it and tab off the field. How do I retain the modified values of cells in the datatable so that I process them in my backing bean.

Comment: Figured it out, values are retained now on tab off. I had business logic in getters. Moving it to another method and calling it from PostConstruct fixed the issue. I am trying to save the whole datatable along with other fields on the form; will add a comment once I an update.

Comment: Hi can you post the code for your solution, I also need to figure out how to back the value of a cell so that I can restore it if my server side validation of it's new edited value fails.